# onclick event handler for elements of a particular div

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, event-handling

I have an event handler that i want to fire only on a click in a particular div id=active. See below.

DOM:

```
<div id='notactive'>
    <span>text</span>
</div>
<div id='active'>
    <span)text2</span>
</div>
```

Event handler that doesn't work as planned:

```
$( "span" ).click(function() {
    alert("active");
}
```

Comment: Is your second span element meant to be malformed or was that a typo?

Comment: css selector works for jquery so : $('#active > span').click() will correctly trigger the span inside the right div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the child of `#active`:

```
$('#active span').on('click', function () {
  alert('active');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

do like this, this event will be fired only in the case of div with id active:

```
$('div#active span').on('click', function () {
  alert('active');
});
```